# How do I access a partial filename from Twig in October CMS?

Tags: php, twig, octobercms

I would like to have access to the current partial filename on Twig in October CMS.

I did a dump of everything and there is a filename on `this.layout.components.localePicker.controller.loader.obj.attributes.fileName` but since `loader` is private I can't access it. Is there any way to access the current layout filename?

Comment: please provide more information to get an answer for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the current templatename then u can access this with global variable `{{ _self }}`

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/v5dlrx)

[documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#global-variables)